# start session on page_load in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, session, master-pages, asp.net

i have 1 master page with 5 pages that call it. now on the master page, I have few dropdowns and textboxes, and the calling pages only have a small article in the corner. I want to start a session on page_load event, so that if the user chooses to select a dropdown or put data in textbox, even if he clicks on the other 4 links of other pages, the data should stay.
how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the values of the controls in Session State, then read them back in Page_Load.